How do I get the json response from the API?
I am trying to read the property response from airbnb via the API but I somehow can't get a proper result and I don't know what I do wrong.
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

def fetch_airbnb_data():
    api_url = "https://www.airbnb.co.uk/api/v3/StaysPdpSections/3bcbe9ee20da9daa6722934f0b54ef68db41699d179e698c3aeab4ec30a964cb?operationName=StaysPdpSections&locale=en-GB&currency=GBP&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%22U3RheUxpc3Rpbmc6MTAyNzQ1NzkyNDI2OTA2NDk4OQ%3D%3D%22%2C%22pdpSectionsRequest%22%3A%7B%22adults%22%3A%221%22%2C%22amenityFilters%22%3Anull%2C%22bypassTargetings%22%3Afalse%2C%22categoryTag%22%3Anull%2C%22children%22%3Anull%2C%22disasterId%22%3Anull%2C%22discountedGuestFeeVersion%22%3Anull%2C%22displayExtensions%22%3Anull%2C%22federatedSearchId%22%3Anull%2C%22forceBoostPriorityMessageType%22%3Anull%2C%22hostPreview%22%3Afalse%2C%22infants%22%3Anull%2C%22interactionType%22%3Anull%2C%22layouts%22%3A%5B%22SIDEBAR%22%2C%22SINGLE_COLUMN%22%5D%2C%22pets%22%3A0%2C%22pdpTypeOverride%22%3Anull%2C%22photoId%22%3Anull%2C%22preview%22%3Afalse%2C%22previousStateCheckIn%22%3Anull%2C%22previousStateCheckOut%22%3Anull%2C%22priceDropSource%22%3Anull%2C%22privateBooking%22%3Afalse%2C%22promotionUuid%22%3Anull%2C%22relaxedAmenityIds%22%3Anull%2C%22searchId%22%3Anull%2C%22selectedCancellationPolicyId%22%3Anull%2C%22selectedRatePlanId%22%3Anull%2C%22splitStays%22%3Anull%2C%22staysBookingMigrationEnabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22translateUgc%22%3Anull%2C%22useNewSectionWrapperApi%22%3Afalse%2C%22sectionIds%22%3Anull%2C%22checkIn%22%3Anull%2C%22checkOut%22%3Anull%2C%22p3ImpressionId%22%3A%22p3_1729488926_P3eUXvpmVbFyX_Cq%22%7D%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22version%22%3A1%2C%22sha256Hash%22%3A%223bcbe9ee20da9daa6722934f0b54ef68db41699d179e698c3aeab4ec30a964cb%22%7D%7D"
    
    try:
        jsonurl = urlopen(api_url)
        data = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data: {e}")

fetch_airbnb_data()

I get the following error:
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Response not successful: Received status code 400",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 1,
                    "column": 1
                }
            ],
            "path": [],
            "extensions": {
                "response": {
                    "statusCode": 400,
                    "body": {
                        "error_code": 400,
                        "error": "invalid_key",
                        "error_message": "Invalid API key."
                    }
                },
                "code": "Bad Request"
            }
        }
    ],
    "data": null
}```


As the error_message says, your API key is invalid. So, change your API Key

Please review HTTP 400

You are right, I forgot to add the API Key at all, so that's why it's "invalid".
I used this:
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'x-airbnb-api-key': 'd306zoyjsyarp7ifhu67rjxn52tv0t20',  # Replace with your correct API key
}

But the issue persisted. I could solve it by copying the other answer, but I am still not sure why my version didn't work properly. Issue is resolved though.

I think it is much more convenient to use the requests library for these purposes
It is better to pass the request parameters in params, and not in the address itself via "?"
You can use https://curlconverter.com to translate the curl request into some programming language
import requests

response = requests.get(
    url='https://www.airbnb.co.uk/api/v3/StaysPdpSections/3bcbe9ee20da9daa6722934f0b54ef68db41699d179e698c3aeab4ec30a964cb',
    params={
    'operationName': 'StaysPdpSections',
    'locale': 'en-GB',
    'currency': 'GBP',
    'variables': '{"id":"U3RheUxpc3Rpbmc6MTAyNzQ1NzkyNDI2OTA2NDk4OQ==","pdpSectionsRequest":{"adults":"1","amenityFilters":null,"bypassTargetings":false,"categoryTag":null,"children":null,"disasterId":null,"discountedGuestFeeVersion":null,"displayExtensions":null,"federatedSearchId":null,"forceBoostPriorityMessageType":null,"hostPreview":false,"infants":null,"interactionType":null,"layouts":["SIDEBAR","SINGLE_COLUMN"],"pets":0,"pdpTypeOverride":null,"photoId":null,"preview":false,"previousStateCheckIn":null,"previousStateCheckOut":null,"priceDropSource":null,"privateBooking":false,"promotionUuid":null,"relaxedAmenityIds":null,"searchId":null,"selectedCancellationPolicyId":null,"selectedRatePlanId":null,"splitStays":null,"staysBookingMigrationEnabled":false,"translateUgc":null,"useNewSectionWrapperApi":false,"sectionIds":null,"checkIn":null,"checkOut":null,"p3ImpressionId":"p3_1729488926_P3eUXvpmVbFyX_Cq"}}',
    'extensions': '{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"3bcbe9ee20da9daa6722934f0b54ef68db41699d179e698c3aeab4ec30a964cb"}}',
}
)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())

It's strange that it has a response code of 200, but in the body of the response itself
{'errors': [{'message': 'Response not successful: Received status code 400', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 1}], 'path': [], 'extensions': {'response': {'statusCode': 400, 'body': {'error_code': 400, 'error': 'invalid_key', 'error_message': 'Invalid API key.'}}, 'code': 'Bad Request'}}], 'data': None}


Thank you, this actually resolved my issue. I forgot to add the API key again in my version, which didn't help. But not sure why my variation doesn't work. I can use yours for now, but need to learn this more deeply. Thank you for your prompt help

As suggested in the error response, you need to add in an API key.
I'd suggest reading the documentation properly and using the requests library for API calls, the method you're using right now is performing a simple GET request without any parameters.
Could you also share the API documentation? Because I could not find any API documentation for the v3 API.

There are multiple query parameters within the URL
